# How retrieve data from an API in JSON to a list in React.Js

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve data from an API in React.Js but there is an small issue with the componentDidMount function.

Here is the API   https://projects.cmsbox.in/app/bms/movie/public/api/upcomingMovie

I have tried this code with other API and it worked but in this case its not working. Also checked the API in Postman and everything seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance :)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import MovieCard from './moviecard'
import Homepage from './homepage';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

class UpcommingMovies extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            upcmngmovie_list: [],
            dataList:[],
            isLoaded:false,
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://projects.cmsbox.in/app/bms/movie/public/api/upcomingMovie')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
          this.setState({
            isLoaded:true,
            dataList:data,
            upcmngmovie_list:dataList,
          })
        });
      }


    render(){

        var{isLoaded,upcmngmovie_list}=this.state;

        function upcomngmoviecards(val){
            return(
                <div className="row"><MovieCard image={val.image} movie_name={val.movie_name}/></div>
            );
        }

        if(!isLoaded){
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          }

        else{
            return (
                <>
                    <Homepage />
                    <div className="main">
                        <h3>Upcomming Movies</h3>
                        <div className="cardlist">
        
                            {upcmngmovie_list.map(upcomngmoviecards)}
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        }

    }
    
}

export default UpcommingMovies;
```

Comment: "There is a small issue" is not really helpful, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The api does not return an array it is returning an object. Array is in "Movie_list" property. Update your set state function to use the property.

```
this.setState({
   isLoaded:true,
   dataList:data,
   upcmngmovie_list:data.Movie_list,
})
```